# chat.postMessage in slack not working when userId is passed to channel field

Tags: slack, slack-api, bolt

I am creating an slack app which posts polls and quizzes to channels and specific users. I'm using chat.postMessage() for that. I have used conversations_select type input field in modal to select a channel/user. When I select a channel from that list and its value is passed to chat.postMessage() it's successfully posting the polls/quizzes. But when I select user from the list and pass the userID to chat.postMessage() method as a channel field it doesn't work.
How should I go about it.

//Quiz Main screen UI

```
app.action("quizstart", async ({ ack, body, context, client }) => {
  // Acknowledge the button request
  ack();

  try {
    const result = await app.client.views.update({
      token: context.botToken,
      // Pass the view_id
      view_id: body.view.id,
      // View payload with updated blocks
      view: {
        type: "modal",
        // View identifier
        callback_id: "quiz_view",
        title: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "Quiz"
        },
        close: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "Cancel",
          emoji: true
        },
        blocks: [
          {
            dispatch_action: true,
            type: "input",
            element: {
              type: "plain_text_input",
              dispatch_action_config: {
                trigger_actions_on: ["on_character_entered"]
              },
                action_id: "question_input_field"  //ooy


            },
            label: {
              type: "plain_text",
              text: "Question",
              emoji: true
            }
          },
          {
            dispatch_action: true,
            type: "input",
            element: {
              type: "plain_text_input",
              dispatch_action_config: {
                trigger_actions_on: ["on_character_entered"]
              },
              action_id: "plain_text_input_action"
            },
            label: {
              type: "plain_text",
              text: "Choice A",
              emoji: true
            },
            optional: true
          },
          {
            dispatch_action: true,
            type: "input",
            element: {
              type: "plain_text_input",
              dispatch_action_config: {
                trigger_actions_on: ["on_character_entered"]
              },
              action_id: "plain_text_input_action"
            },
            label: {
              type: "plain_text",
              text: "Choice B",
              emoji: true
            },
            optional: true
          },
          {
            dispatch_action: true,
            type: "input",
            element: {
              type: "plain_text_input",
              dispatch_action_config: {
                trigger_actions_on: ["on_character_entered"]
              },
              action_id: "plain_text_input_action"
            },
            label: {
              type: "plain_text",
              text: "Choice C",
              emoji: true
            },
            optional: true
          },
          {
            dispatch_action: true,
            type: "input",
            element: {
              type: "plain_text_input",
              dispatch_action_config: {
                trigger_actions_on: ["on_character_entered"]
              },
              action_id: "plain_text_input_action"
            },
            label: {
              type: "plain_text",
              text: "Choice D",
              emoji: true
            },
            optional: true
          },
          {
            dispatch_action: true,
            type: "input",
            element: {
              type: "plain_text_input",
              dispatch_action_config: {
                trigger_actions_on: ["on_character_entered"]
              },
              action_id: "plain_text_input_action"
            },
            label: {
              type: "plain_text",
              text: "Choice E",
              emoji: true
            },
            optional: true
          },
          {
            dispatch_action: true,
            type: "input",
            element: {
              type: "plain_text_input",
              dispatch_action_config: {
                trigger_actions_on: ["on_character_entered"]
              },
              action_id: "correct_answer_action"
            },
            label: {
              type: "plain_text",
              text: "Correct Answer",
              emoji: true
            },
            optional: false
          },
          {
            dispatch_action: true,
            type: "input",
            element: {
              type: "plain_text_input",
              dispatch_action_config: {
                trigger_actions_on: ["on_character_entered"]
              },
              action_id: "quizname_action"
            },
            label: {
              type: "plain_text",
              text: "Quiz name",
              emoji: true
            },
            optional: false
          },
          {
            type: "section",
            text: {
              type: "mrkdwn",
              text:
                "Here you can configure your *WebMobi Poll*. (<https://google.com|learn more>)"
            }
          },
          {
            type: "divider"
          },
          {
            type: "section",
            text: {
              type: "mrkdwn",
              text: "*Audience*"
            }
          },
          {
            type: "actions",
            elements: [
              {
                type: "conversations_select",
                placeholder: {
                  type: "plain_text",
                  text: "conversations", //730
                  emoji: true
                },
                action_id: "select_channel_menu"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            type: "section",
            text: {
              type: "mrkdwn",
              text: "*Advanced Settings*"
            }
          },
          {
            type: "section",
            text: {
              type: "mrkdwn",
              text: ":clipboard: *Anonymus*\nChoose to send poll as anonymous"
            },
            accessory: {
              type: "static_select",
              placeholder: {
                type: "plain_text",
                text: "Select",
                emoji: true
              },
              options: [
                {
                  text: {
                    type: "plain_text",
                    text: "True",
                    emoji: true
                  },
                  value: "value-anonymus1"
                },
                {
                  text: {
                    type: "plain_text",
                    text: "False",
                    emoji: true
                  },
                  value: "value-anonymus2"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
         
        ],
        submit: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "Submit"

        }
      }
    });
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

//app.view for view submission 
// main question UI
app.view("quiz_view", async ({ ack, body, view, context }) => {
  await ack();
  console.log("inside quiz view app.view " + view.id);
  const val1 = view["state"]["values"];
  const user1 = body["user"]["id"];
  const user2 = body["user"]["name"];
  
  var quiz_id = await makeQuizPostRequest(val1, user1, user2);
  publishMessageQuiz(val1, user1, user2, quiz_id,body);
  console.log(quiz_id);
});

async function makeQuizPostRequest(val1, user1, user2) {
  const x = val1;
  console.log(x);
const ques = Object.values(x)[0].question_input_field.value;
  console.log("before ques console");
  console.log("ques " + ques);
  const opt1 = Object.values(x)[1].plain_text_input_action.value;
  console.log("opt1 " +opt1);
  const opt2 = Object.values(x)[2].plain_text_input_action.value;
    console.log("opt2 " +opt2);

  const opt3 = Object.values(x)[3].plain_text_input_action.value;
    console.log("opt3 " +opt3);

  const opt4 = Object.values(x)[4].plain_text_input_action.value;
    console.log("opt4 " +opt4);

  const opt5 = Object.values(x)[5].plain_text_input_action.value;
    console.log("opt5 " +opt5);
  
  const correctAns= Object.values(x)[6].correct_answer_action.value;
    console.log("correctAns  " + correctAns);
  
  const quizname = Object.values(x)[7].quizname_action.value;
      console.log(" quizname " + quizname);

  
  const channel = Object.values(x)[8].select_channel_menu.selected_conversation;
 var options = new Array(7);
  if (opt1 != null) {
      console.log(opt1);

    options.push(opt1);
  }
  if (opt2 != null) {
      console.log(opt2);

    options.push(opt2);
  }
  if (opt3 != null) {
      console.log(opt3);

    options.push(opt3);
  }
  if (opt4 != null) {
      console.log(opt4);

    options.push(opt4);
  }
  if (opt5 != null) {
      console.log(opt5);

    options.push(opt5);
  }
  options.shift();
  options.shift();
  options.shift();
  options.shift();
  options.shift();
  var options1 = options.toString();
  options1 = "[" + options1 + "]";
let payload =
{
    "app_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "created_by": user2,
    "customtheme": false,
    "quizarray": [
        {
            "question": ques,
            "options": options1,
            "correctanswer": correctAns,
            "isActive": true
        }
    ],
    "quiz_name": quizname
}
  let res = await axios.post(
    "https://api_to_create_quiz",
    payload
  );
let data = res.data;
  console.log(data.responseString);

  var quiz_id = res.data.data.quiz_id;
  console.log(quiz_id);
  return quiz_id;
}

//publishMessage for quiz
async function publishMessageQuiz(val1, user1, user2, quiz_id, body) {
  console.log("publishmessage_entry Quiz");
  console.log("quiz_id", quiz_id);
  let x = val1;
  // console.log(x);
  let voteList = [];
  let ques = Object.values(x)[0].question_input_field.value;
  let opt1 = Object.values(x)[1].plain_text_input_action.value;
  let opt2 = Object.values(x)[2].plain_text_input_action.value;
  let opt3 = Object.values(x)[3].plain_text_input_action.value;
  let opt4 = Object.values(x)[4].plain_text_input_action.value;
  let opt5 = Object.values(x)[5].plain_text_input_action.value;
  let correctAns=Object.values(x)[6].correct_answer_action.value;
  let quizname=Object.values(x)[7].quizname_action.value;

  const channel = Object.values(x)[8].select_channel_menu.selected_conversation;
let options = new Array(5);
  if (opt1 != null) {
    options.push(opt1);
  }
  if (opt2 != null) {
    options.push(opt2);
  }
  if (opt3 != null) {
    options.push(opt3);
  }
  if (opt4 != null) {
    options.push(opt4);
  }
  if (opt5 != null) {
    options.push(opt5);
  }
  options.shift();
  options.shift();
  options.shift();
  options.shift();
  options.shift();
  let options1 = options.toString();
let optionList = [];
  let optionButtons = [];
  let optionGraph = [];

  let arr_options = options1.split(",");

  arr_options.forEach(function(main, index) {
    // console.log(main);
    let val_id = "value" + index;
    // console.log(val_id);
    let act_id = "option" + index + "_" + quiz_id;
    console.log(act_id);
    optionButtons.push(act_id);
    console.log(optionButtons);
    let voteObj = {
      type: "button",
      text: {
        type: "plain_text",
        emoji: true,
        text: main
      },
      value: val_id,
      action_id: act_id
    };

    optionList.push(voteObj);
  });

  try {
    // Call the chat.postMessage method using the built-in WebClient
    let result = await app.client.chat.postMessage({
      // The token you used to initialize your app
      token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
      signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
      channel:channel,
      text: "WebMobi Quiz",
      blocks: [
        {
          type: "section",
          text: {
            type: "mrkdwn",
            text: "Quiz question from WebMobi poll"
          }
        },
        {
          type: "section",
          text: {
            type: "mrkdwn",
            text: "*" + ques + "*"
          }
        },
        {
          type: "actions",
          elements: [
            ...optionList
  ]
        },
        {
          type: "divider"
        },
        {
          type: "context",
          elements: [
            {
              type: "mrkdwn",
              text:
                "hello (Sender: " +
                user2 +
                " | :unlock: *Responses*: Non-Anonymous/Anonymous | :clock930: *Status*: "
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          type: "context",
          elements: [
            {
              type: "mrkdwn",
              text:
                ":smile: Get insight of your polls from <https://google.com|WebMobi dashboard>"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });
optionButtons.forEach(el => {
      app.action(el, async ({ ack, body, client }) => {
        // Acknowledge the button request
        await ack();
        // console.log(el);
        console.log("bodymessage", body);
        // console.log("bodymessage", client);
        // console.log("my user id", body.user.id);
        let person = body.user.name;
        let time = body.message.ts;
        console.log("message Body", body);
        // console.log("This is my Email Id",emailId);

        // let result = await postPollApi(poll_id);
        let action = body.actions[0].action_id;
        let optionValue = "";
        let optionResults = [];
        let optionGraphResults = [];
        let pollAnswer = "";
        optionList.forEach(els => {
          let opitonObj = {};
          let optionGraphResultsObj = {};
          let ok = els.text.text;
          if (els.action_id == action) {
            optionValue = els.value;
            opitonObj = {
              type: "button",
              text: {
                type: "plain_text",
                emoji: true,
                text: els.text.text
              },
              value: action,
              style: "primary"
            };
            optionResults.push(opitonObj);
            const red = "█████████████████████████";
            optionGraphResultsObj = {
              type: "section",
              text: {
                type: "mrkdwn",
                text: els.text.text + ": `" + red + "`  |  100% (1)"
              } //option1 + ": `" + graph + "` " + percent + "% (" + noofvotes + ")"
            };
            pollAnswer = els.text.text;
          } else {
            opitonObj = {
              type: "button",
              text: {
                type: "plain_text",
                emoji: true,
                text: els.text.text
              },
              value: action
            };
            optionResults.push(opitonObj);
            const white = "█                        ";
            optionGraphResultsObj = {
              type: "section",
              text: {
                type: "mrkdwn",
                text: els.text.text + ": `" + white + "`  |  0% (0)"
                //els.text.text+"`█                                `  |  0% (0)"
              }
            };
          }
          optionGraphResults.push(optionGraphResultsObj);
        });
        console.log("action id", action);

        let email = await getUserEmail(client, body.user.id);
        console.log("webmobi email id", email);
        let user_webmobi_id = await getuserId(email);
        console.log("webmobi user id", user_webmobi_id);
        // let poll_result = await submitPoll(pollAnswer, poll_id,user_webmobi_id);
        // console.log("submited poll",poll_result);
        try {
          console.log("364 quiz");
          // Call views.update with the built-in client
          const result = await client.chat.update({
            token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
            ts: time,
            response_url: body.response_url,
            response_type: "ephemeral",
            channel: channel,
            text: "Updated quiz results",
            //as_user:true,
            blocks: [
              {
                type: "section",
                text: {
                  type: "mrkdwn",
                  text: `Quiz question from WebMobi poll`
                }
              },
              {
                type: "section",
                text: {
                  type: "mrkdwn",
                  text: ques
                }
              },
              {
                type: "actions",
                elements: [...optionResults]
              },
              //  ...optionGraph
              ...optionGraphResults,
              {
                type: "divider"
              },
              {
                type: "context",
                elements: [
                  {
                    type: "mrkdwn",
                    text:
                      "hello (Sender: user | :unlock: *Responses*: Non-Anonymous/Anonymous | :clock930: *Status*: "
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                type: "context",
                elements: [
                  {
                    type: "mrkdwn",
                    text:
                      ":smile: Get insight of your polls from <https://google.com|WebMobi dashboard>"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          });
          console.log(result);
          console.log("chatpostmessage");
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
    });

    // Print result, which includes information about the message (like TS)
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`chat.postMessage` is a bit tricky in that way.
https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#channels__post-to-a-direct-message-channel

You need to pass the `dmId` instead of `UserId` in `chat.postMessage()`

To get the `dmId`,you will need  `conversations.open` method.

 https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open

**Sample Code in JS**

```
 slackClient.conversations.open({
        users: userId 
        })
        .then(async (res) => {   
        await slackClient.chat.postMessage({
                  channel: res.channel.id,
                  text: text,
                  blocks: blocks
                })        
         }
```